# detect div overflow and do something

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**The scenario:**
I need to create a .pdf file from a webpage. this web pages constructs an A4 sized page with a header, content and footer div. the content div can sometimes contain to much information to fit on 1 page so i need to create a second page if the content div overflows. Every page needs to contain the header, content and footer div. (the div contains page numbers and signatures which need to be on every page)

A colleague has already created a .php file to do this, however if there's to much data the footer div will continue on the next page (talking about actual A4 sized pages). he did all of this by counting lines in the content div. it works for 2 pages but everything more is messed up. So since i'm quite new to .php and html i wanted to dive into it and do things the right way (detecting overflow and then making the new page).

I've tried tweaking the lines allowed on each page but in the end it's just a hack and i know i can detect the overflow in some way but i can't figure out how to make everything work

**The problem:**
counting lines in a div is not reliable, especially since every new piece of data (mileage, hours, expenses) has a small table header which takes up some space on the page as well.
and although I've tried tweaking the line numbers, in the end when the document gets to big the header won't start at the top of the page.
so i want to make this more robust and make sure the sizes of the div's can't change and all the information is shown (meaning no data is hidden since the div is overflowing).

**The question**
How do i start a new 'page' when the current content div is overflowing?

**The code**

```
<?php
    for($pageID = 1; $pageID <= $NumberOfPages; $pageID++){
    $LinesLeft = $linesPerPage;
?>
<div class="header"> Header stuff here </div> // always the same info in this div
<div class="content"> 
 <table border="0" width="100%">      
    <tr>    
      <td valign="top" width="7%">
        <b>Aantal :</b><br>
      </td>

      <td valign="top">
        <b>Materialen :</b><br>           
      </td>       
    </tr>

    <?php 
        for($idx = 0; $idx < $LinesForThisPage; $idx++){
            echo "<tr height=\"22\">     
                  <td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\">" . $Materialen[$anchorB + $idx]['Aantal'] . "</td>
                  <td style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\">" . $Materialen[$anchorB + $idx]['Omschrijving'] . "</td>
              </tr>";
        }
        $anchor += $idx; // anchor is the current index of where i've left with displaying information.
    ?>

  </table>
 </div>
<div class="footer"> footer stuff </div> // always the same info in this div
```

**EDIT**
I've shortened my question considerably and added code.

Comment: Please keep the question to a short set of details about the problem, what you've tried and the code itself.

Comment: yes i know, i just did not see how i could scale it down. well at least i made sure the problem and question were quickly visible, i'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

To detect if the content of a div is overflowing you can compare its `height` to `scrollHeight`. If it overflows, `scrollHeight` will be greater.

```
var $el = $('#foo');
if ($el.height() < $el[0].scrollHeight) {
    console.log('this element is overflowing....');
}
```

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat this is javascript/jquery code

Comment: oke, now with my limited knowledge of java-script: this is done client sided so there is no way my php script would know to start a new page, and java script could not retrieve the data from my database. Can javascript see the content which has overflown and just use that to create a 2nd 'page'?

Comment: I don't understand: <<my php script would know to start a new page>> ??? Is it pagination what you are talking about? Without seeing any relevant code, it's quite impossible to help you more

Comment: yes i do apologize for that, i posted to soon, should have done it properly (see my question I've changed it accordingly)

Comment: I think you should really think about using more robust solution to expose your data, e.g: http://datatables.net/

Comment: well as i said, most of it isn't my data, my colegue kinda trew it at me saying he did not have time to fix it.
I just added some for loops and some if statements in the hope of 'fixing' it.